# The argument type 'MaterialApp Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)'

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax-error

[Anyone to help ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p29iI.png)

I've been using someone else's project. It seems like the code is outdated as flutter gets updates. Would u guys take a look? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context , child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'First Method',
          // You can use the library anywhere in the app even in theme
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: Typography.englishLike2018.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.sp),
          ),
          home: child,
        );
      },
      child: const HomePage(title: 'First Method'),
    );
  }
```

In your builder constructor pass context and child first. Then in home pass child. Next, set your HomePage to the child of the ScreenUtilInit. Hope its clear.

Comment: well, the app stuck working, but we have at least solved 1 issue xd

Comment: what did you do now? what error? You should mark it as an answer if it solved your previous error.